# How to send an email in Angular

Tags: html, angular, email

I'm interested in sending an email in Agular or in Typescript in such a way that they click on a certain email address and then it will open in Gmail
And can't do it in any way

Comment: `<a href="mailto:abc@example.com">Send Email</a>` All you need to do is include `mailto:` and navigate there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To open an email using the user's preferred email client you can use a normal anchor tag:

```html
<a href="mailto:SOME_EMAIL">Send an email</a>
```

You can also handle phone numbers and other types this way: [Mozilla Docs for Anchor Tags](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-href)